# RE Huawei HG8145V5 user credentials

Tags: encryption

I have Huawei HG8145V5 and I backed up config file which contains encrypted root and admin credentials, but I dont know how they are encrypted. Here is an example of one password

```
$2*FuHXY&lt;y5$VJl(9f^9z%7;vR%K;84JG$.&amp;O`qM17$
```

Can anyone identify which algo is used ?

Comment: For your: $2*FuHXY&lt;y5$VJl(9f^9z%7;vR%K;84JG$.&amp;O`qM17$ here is the decrypt code: gcmoct

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. It would be helpful to add how/where you retrieved this information.

Comment: How did you decrypted it ?

Comment: @bloosky how did you decrypted it ?

Comment: How did u solve this i have the same router

Answer (score 3):

It's probably AES. I saw config files at HG8245Hv5 and HG8245H5 and passwords are looking similar. A bit (just a bit:D) more info is here: https://the-infosec.com/2017/03/20/huawei-hg8245h-router-privilege-escalatio/

Comment: Also mr. Vido I have one question for you too:) Could you please reply on this post if you're reading it?

Comment: Hey @HE9CbITb tnx for your replay it seams that enc. is aes

Comment: Hi, @Vido I have one question for you:) In this topic https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/zte-encrypted-backup-config-file the issue of decrypting modem config file was discussed. It was recommended to find a file named 'tagparam_m', perform MD5sum of it, get this way AES-key, decrypt config file with this key, decompress zlib and finally get config file in xml. I want to ask you: where did you find this 'tagparam_m' file? I'm looking at firmware file directories (including /var), but I can't find this file. Thank you:)

Comment: Hey @HE9CblTb in my case `tagparam_m` was in `var` directory

Comment: Ok, maybe that's because of different firmware. Gonna search again. Thank you:)

Comment: Hey @HE9CbITb which router do you have ?

Comment: @Vido I have ZTE F609 (Software Version V7.0.10P7N1).

Comment: Hey @HE9CbITb I assume that you connected via telnet and you looking at `/var` right ? Also can you send me your cspd ?

Comment: @Vido no, I'm looking at firmware file. I can't telnet modem because I don't know correct login/password (I tried many different variants: ```root/Zte521```, ```root/root```, ```root/Telkom135``` and another - noone worked). I wanted to get config file to look at these login/password, but this file is probably encrypted (```binwalk``` shows just rising enthropy egde; it seems to me that file is encrypted). I read that topic (ZTE encrypted config), it was recommended to find a file ```tagparam_m``` but since I can't get access to modem I've started to analyze firmware file in hope to find smth.

Comment: Hey  @HE9CbITb Can you send me your firmware

Comment: @Vido yeah, I can, but not tonight. I'll be home day after tomorrow so then I'll send you it. Just tell me where should I send it. And once again thank you for helping:)  By the way I think telnet can be just disabled in this firmware, but we always need to know such things for sure, right?:)

Comment: Hey @HE9CbITb you can upload it somewhere mega.nz for example. If it's accepts `root` user as user when you try to log in then I think its working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118384/discussion-between-vido-and-he9cbitb).