# Need Help with decryption backup config.bin file "ZTE ZXHN H267N v1.1"

Tags: tools, encryption, decryption

hi i'm trying to decrypt config.bin file from new router I got from my company, I tried a tool found on github "https://github.com/mkst/zte-config-utility" I got this ERROR:

```
python3 examples/decode.py --key 'tHG@Ti&GVh@ql3XN' --serial 'ZTEFG7GL7B112171' config.bin config.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples/decode.py", line 41, in <module>
    main()
  File "examples/decode.py", line 36, in main
    payload_type = zcu.zte.read_payload_type(infile)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zcu-0.1.0-py3.8.egg/zcu/zte.py", line 51, in read_payload_type
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zcu-0.1.0-py3.8.egg/zcu/zte.py", line 45, in read_payload
AssertionError
```

binwalk gives me:

```
binwalk -E -N config.bin

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     ENTROPY
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             Rising entropy edge (0.950362)
18432         0x4800          Falling entropy edge (0.617036)
```

```
binwalk -W config.bin

OFFSET      config.bin
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x00000000  04 03 02 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0F 5A 58 48 4E |............ZXHN|
0x00000010  20 48 32 36 37 4E 20 56 31 2E 31 01 02 03 04 00 |.H267N.V1.1.....|
0x00000020  00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................|
0x00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................|
0x00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................|
0x00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 47 B0 00 00 47 C0 00 |.........G...G..|
0x00000060  00 00 00 70 B0 93 D8 95 41 0B 8B A6 26 7B 59 35 |...p....A...&{Y5|
0x00000070  44 77 FF 9C 74 B2 02 15 29 F9 28 EA 5A F2 C5 84 |Dw..t...).(.Z...|
0x00000080  66 B1 2C 3E 10 5A 76 AA 2D D1 9E 9D AA 6E 49 1E |f.,>.Zv.-....nI.|
0x00000090  5F A1 6D 0D 42 E0 6C E9 D9 84 81 23 99 5A B5 22 |_.m.B.l....#.Z."|
0x000000A0  09 BC 78 5A CB EF AF 4B D7 1E A2 40 D4 11 7F 7E |..xZ...K...@...~|
0x000000B0  EE EC DC E8 D7 CC 9C 8B EE BD 02 6C A7 BB F8 B6 |...........l....|
0x000000C0  76 01 2F 0A CD CE F4 B1 02 BF A9 C3 37 D1 3D 44 |v./.........7.=D|
0x000000D0  80 55 DD C9 DB 59 70 1C D9 9F DA 89 D6 04 14 66 |.U...Yp........f|
0x000000E0  AA 9B 77 AE 1D BB 0C C0 BF 2F F2 86 3D 3B E5 CA |..w....../..=;..|
0x000000F0  1E EF 25 2D 44 02 09 DE 6A BF 3A 91 56 65 58 6E |..%-D...j.:.VeXn|
0x00000100  B2 7B 5F 18 1F 18 90 3E 43 56 B8 9A 1A 5B 3A BC |.{_....>CV...[:.|
0x00000110  6E D0 5B 44 5F 2B 9E CC BC F4 12 8B 61 50 E4 C8 |n.[D_+......aP..|
0x00000120  1C 50 FF B9 2F 1E 34 83 57 63 72 45 5E E4 83 17 |.P../.4.WcrE^...|
0x00000130  8F ED 29 AC 0E 27 DF FD 30 C1 63 44 D2 35 2F E9 |..)..'..0.cD.5/.|
0x00000140  65 5B 6A AA 39 54 9D 5C 34 29 63 43 C6 1D 67 80 |e[j.9T.\4)cC..g.|
0x00000150  89 7B EB 08 A3 30 A9 67 A8 C0 38 EA B4 B1 7B 45 |.{...0.g..8...{E|
0x00000160  6D C5 3A A6 FC 90 52 05 20 62 E0 82 C8 A3 76 98 |m.:...R..b....v.|
0x00000170  D9 D8 7D B1 BE CC 1A B6 15 CA BB 85 5B 15 EE 1D |..}.........[...|
```

any idea guys to decrypt config.bin file

Comment: Why are you trying that key in particular?

Comment: i want authentication login to dsl so I can change the router the company gave me because they don't allow me to change this router and it hung on wireless connection

Comment: The assert is `assert payload_header[0] == constants.PAYLOAD_MAGIC` so either your image is in a different format than zte-config-utility expects, or you've got the decryption key wrong. Where did you get `--key 'tHG@Ti&GVh@ql3XN'` from? Why are you trying that key in particular?

Comment: But obviously if your company insist you use this router and the router is hanging then you should talk to them about it and get them to resolve the problem, e.g. fix the configuration or give you a different router, rather than trying to hack the one you've got.

Comment: i found the key here in https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/25255/35141 i knew the key may be wrong and not working for this version, the company does not give you the possibility to use other router and the only router they give you is this ZTE and i already asked them but no answer man i dont want to fix configuration i want to change the router and i need DSL authentication username and password to use it in other router and the login info are in the backup bin file not firmware bin file so i'm trying to get my personal info not hacking the router here hhhh

Comment: plz anyone knows how to find encryption key

Comment: From the other thread you've already linked to, it looks like you'll have to read it off the router itself - if you have a way of accessing its filesystem - either from the cspd binary or from an md5sum of /var/tagparam_m.

Comment: unfortunately there is no way to access the router only backup file I can download telnet port is closed

Comment: Any Acheivements? and can u give me ur email address please?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?
iam from morocco

Comment: no but i did contact theme many times till they gave me the credentials for adsl connection so i'm able to use better router and that is what i did really LOL

Comment: i can't put my email here if you need more information we can figure out how to contact each other