# PPPoE username and password from ZTE ZXHN F680 V6

Tags: firmware, router

I'm trying to extract the PPPoE username and password from a **ZTE ZXHN F680 V6** router. I have obtained several files from the router and can get access to other files if needed.  Here is where I'm at.

I have obtained the `cspd` file after reading [this Q&A](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/zte-encrypted-backup-config-file).  I also have a `config.bin` file but was unable to determine any information from it using `binwalk` or `strings` commnads.  Both returned empty results and indicated high level of entropy.

[Here is a link to the files extracted from router.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UEV9xGcFIq4aQfRj-k9_uJx4CEPirykA)

I assume that the PPPoE file will be in an encoded or encrypted or both .xml file.  So, my search in the `cspd` file for strings resulted in potentially useful information.

```
$ strings cspd | grep .xml
/var/tmp/db_user_cfg.xml
CP download xml doc failed!
/etc/db_user_cfg.xml
please input cfg file(/proc/cfg/db_user_cfg.xml) eg.
/var/tmp/db_cp_cfg.xml
/var/tmp/db_reload_cfg.xml
/var/tmp/db_backup_cfg.xml
/etc/db_default_%s_cfg.xml
/var/tmp/db_Decry_cfg.xml
/var/tmp/usb_rst_cfg.xml
dbc_mgr_file_xml.c
at %d line of xml file
sbsize(%d) xmlsize(%d)
/userconfig/cfg/db_user_cfg.xml
/etc/db_default_cfg.xml
/userconfig/cfg/db_backup_cfg.xml
```

I think the best candidates for containing the PPPoE username and password are `/userconfig/cfg/db_backup_cfg.xml`,  `/userconfig/cfg/db_user_cfg.xml` and `/etc/db_default_cfg.xml`.

I have checked those files using `binwalk` and it seems they are high level of entropy with only one section (no obvious header), so have been encrypted, not simply encoded:

```
binwalk -E db_user_cfg.xml

WARNING: Failed to import matplotlib module, visual entropy graphing will be disabled

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     ENTROPY
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             Rising entropy edge (0.954061)
```

I following the above linked post I have used Ghidra 10 to de-compile the `cspd` file and searched for these strings, as well as functions for decryption.  I found the following files:

- AES_set_decryption_key
- AESDecrypt
- AESCBCDecry
- **dbcCfgSetAesKey**
- DecryByAES
- DecryByAESCBC

I think the most likely candidate to get a key for decryption is `dbcCfgSetAesKey`, but that's only because of the name of the function and the target .xml files have **cfg** in their names.

The body of the `dbcCfgSetAesKey` function is below.  It only accepts one variable and :

```
undefined4 dbcCfgSetAesKey(void *param_1)

{
  if (param_1 != (void *)0x0) {
    memcpy(g_szMD5Key,param_1,0x20);
    return 0;
  }
  return 0xffffffff;
}
```

I searched Ghidra for `g_szMD5Key` and found there was only a Label with that name, no function. It appears to me that the above `dbcCfgSetAesKey` function is copying the config file AES key to a memory location to be accessed later by the decryption process.  They key may be some type of MD5 hash?

My questions are:

1. What are my options for extracting the key to decrypt the .xml files?  Am I right that they PPPoE data will likely be in the above mentioned .xml files?
2. Am I generally on the right track to extract config data from a ZTE router such as ZTE ZXHN F680 V6?  I know that they are all different, and have looked at some other tools such as [zte-config-utility](https://github.com/mkst/zte-config-utility) which I see requires having a key to extract the config files.
3. What am I missing about this approach to reverse-compiling the router configuration.

I know my questions will be rather noob since I am just starting to learn reverse engineering / compiling.  I am fairly good with encryption and modes, but not create with Ghidra or C++.  If my question is much to simple and uninformed just let me know.

Comment: Can you upload cspd file?

Comment: @xax I have uploaded a zip file of the files extracted from the router.  There is also a directory tagparam with a p12 certificate, and config.bin.  All seem encrypted. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UEV9xGcFIq4aQfRj-k9_uJx4CEPirykA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This config file using **AES-256-CBC** algorithm and **deflate zlib** compression.
key_str = "C1DB7A773d634602dc8c", iv_str = "ZTE%FN$GponNJ025" ->
key = sha256(key_str), iv = first 16byte of sha256(iv_str) ->
key = **4a5e07466a0777eb2650bbd4fc85bb7498e3048d4219916c5f50576ad5c25bce**
iv    = **83197b65889558bb6723df979895bb36**
Decrypt method in  function **DecryByAESCBC** and key_str **C1DB7A773d634602dc8c** I find from **paramtag** file.
But this decrypt success only file **db_backup_cfg.xml**.

Comment: Thanks for that info.  I assume that the zlib decompress must happen first because when I open the file as bytes in Python3 and check the length of the db_backup_cfg.xml file `print(len(payload) % 16)` the output is 8.  So the file is not padded the right length for  AES 256 CBC mode decryption.  But when I try to zlib decompress using python3, `payload = zlib.decompress(payload)` I get the error, `zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check`.

Comment: [hex view](https://imgur.com/a/E9S2YWw)
You can use **decode.py db_backup_cfg.bin db_backup_cfg.xml** after decrypt or using my script using zcu [zte_f608.py](https://pastebin.com/CCqm1tfj) **zte_f608.py --key-prefix C1DB7A773d634602dc8c --iv-prefix ZTE%FN$GponNJ025 db_backup_cfg.xml out.xml**

Comment: I tried your command `python3 zte_f608.py --key-prefix C1DB7A773d634602dc8c --iv-prefix ZTE%FN$GponNJ025 db_backup_cfg.xml out.xml` for the script but the error: Malformed decrypted payload, likely you used the wrong key!

Comment: **db_backup_cfg.xml** only, I don't know key of file **config.bin** and **db_user_cfg.xml**

Comment: Hm.. that's strange. I tried this command on the **db_backup_cfg.xml file**: `python3 zte_f608.py --key-prefix C1DB7A773d634602dc8c --iv-prefix ZTE%FN$GponNJ025 db_backup_cfg.xml out.xml`.  Like I said, I got the error used the wrong key!  Did that command exactly work for you on **db_backup_cfg.xml file**?

Comment: You can see [db_backup_cfg.xml.bin](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dVLASR88euSVFI7y5_JwQB3KCpnz_83k/view?usp=sharing) file I using **zte_f608.py** decrypt success to compress file, you can decode to xml use **zte_f608.py** or **decode.py**

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to zlib decompress the **db_backup_cfg.xml.bin** file using the zte_f608.py tool as you mentioned since it seems to skip the the decryption process if it can't detect the payload_type.  So, that worked.  I'm not sure why I could not also decrypt it.  Thanks though!

Comment: can you tell me please how did you managed to access the router, I have the same model and i'm struggling.?<br/>
Also I have another ZTE router(*F660v5*) that i was able to have shell on it, but again, i wasn't able to decrypt the config...

Comment: i have the some model can you show me plz by steps how did you extract the file from the router
thx

Comment: Is there anyway you can share with us the firmware? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you share the firmware as a bin file?
And are we talking about the ZTE F680 V6 or another variant? because you got me wondering with the -L suffix.
Thank you