# How to decrypt the config.bin from ZTE ZXV10 H201L

Tags: binary-analysis, linux, decryption

I have this file from my router its backup of user config,I suppose its compresed with zlib and encrypted with AES. Utility which is resposible to compress it and encrypt it is called [cspd](https://mega.nz/#!tIRxEApS!5FAbRXIwNZd7kmve94jmK37QWOLdfZ_Hv6PNhLSKfZ4). In side cspd there is function called `dbcCfgFileDecry` in which Im interested, If anyone could help me identify how this function decrypt config file I would be most grateful.I can run gdbserver on router with cspd as argument but it just exit, I also tried to attach to existing cspd proces (there is several of them) but router just crashes.

EDIT: I just found that inside `encry` function there is `CSPDBGetFileEncryKey` so the key is stored inside DB ?? There is also utility on router caled [sendcmd](https://mega.nz/#!AMR3HA5J!hnIwDa7Kw9NxUiNs8o7vNPyMSK0ptzSaiYl33zWDCb8) which is responsable in manipulating of DB. If I run sendcmd with `sendcmd 1 DB` I get

```
fc [bin-file-name]:compress user config to bin-file-name
fuc [bin-file-name]:uncompress bin-file-name to user config
decry : cfg decry
```

I did tried it but it does not work

Comment: Are you still wanting to solve this?

Comment: yes I'm  wanting  to solve this

Comment: Could you (re) upload your config.bin and cspd binary?

Answer (score 1):

How does this question differ to your question [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14711/identify-compression-of-this-zte-zxv10-h201l-v2-backup-config-file)?

Your key is `Renjx%2$CjM`.

You can use the [zcu](https://github.com/streetster/zte-config-utility) module I have written to decode your configuration file e.g.

```
$ python3 examples/decode.py config.bin config.xml --key 'Renjx%2$CjM'
$ head config.xml
<DB>
<Tbl name="DBBase" RowCount="1">
<Row No="0">
<DM name="IFInfo" val="0101010004000000010601000000021244010000440200004403000044040000"/>
</Row>
</Tbl>
<Tbl name="ETH" RowCount="4">
<Row No="0">
<DM name="ViewName" val="IGD.LD1.ETH1"/>
<DM name="LDWDViewName" val="IGD.LD1"/>
```

Comment: Can you decrypt my router config ZTE H168N V 2.2 ... i cannot get the keys